# Two offers, both to get the Habilitation: better a 3+3 years position in a German University, or a 2 years position in a Swiss University?

Tags: postdocs, professorship, germany, switzerland, habilitation

It happened that 2 offers for similar positions, which goal would be to get the Habilitation, occured at the same time.

One position would be a 3+3 years in one of the best German Universities, while the second would be a 2 years position in a very good university in Switzerland (as a continuation of a postdoc in the same department).

My doubt would be: if the same "degree" of Habilitation could be achieved in a 2 years position (in Switzerland), what could be the benefits to go for the 3+3 years position in Germany?

In particular, if, after the habilitation, you always need to look and apply for a professorship, and likely change working place.

In other words, isn't it better to get the Habilitation as fast as possible, in order to apply for a professorship as soon as possible?

Or maybe there are pros and better benefits to get the Habilitation in Germany in a longer period than in Switzerland, in a shorter period.

In addition, if I understood correctly, many consider the period of getting the Habilitation still as a postdoc phase instead of a sort of professorship. So, isn't it better to keep that period of Habilitation as short as possible, in order to get the title of professor as soon as possible ?

Comments and thoughts are very welcome!

Comment: Is this due to you wanting to get it fast, or you want to live in Switzerland over Germany?

Comment: Are you sure that the 2-year position has the explicit goal that you will be finished with your Habilitation after the two years? Sounds rather unusual to me. Perhaps it's meant as a first position which could be followed by other positions with the ultimate goal of Habilitation.

Comment: Thanks @NAMcMahon, Yes, to be done fast since I have already 5 years of postdocs

Comment: Thanks @lighthousekeeper! Well, since several years of postdocs are already done, the people in charge who offered the position to get the Habilitation estimated 2 years... Exactly for the reason that already some years of postdocs has been done...

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. In that case, you probably have significant achievements from your postdocs that count for the Habilitation. Probably these achievements would also count for your Habilitation case for the position in Germany, and allow you to complete the Habilitation in much shorter time than 6 years. In that case, the benefit of the German position would be clear, as you could approach your professorship job search from a more relaxed position.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper many thanks for your valuable insights, very interesting :-)

Comment: @limone: It was not my intention to offend you and I'm sorry if I yet did so. I was trying to better understand your background since my impression of German academia considerably differs from yours, as evidenced by several sentences in your post. (I don't understand why you see a relation to English language, though.) Anyway, I deleted my comment since it apparently failed its purpose

Comment: @jochenGlueck I deleted mine as well.. btw, I don't really know so much about the German system... And just a little about the Swiss one... For this reason, I ask here, in this forum, for some hints or different perspectives that I likely don't know about..

Comment: Have a look at the "Habilitationsordnung" (habilitation rules) of the universities. At mine (Germany) habilitation is supposed to take 4 years, no matter what position you are in (a 3+3 "Hausstelle", a 4-5 year position on a DFG grant, or something else)

Comment: and don't forget that you don't need a habilitation in order to apply/get a professorship position, neither in germany nor in other countries (most don't have a habilitation program at all)

Comment: It sounds like you're already a postdoc at the Swiss university? If so, talk to your current supervisor. They'll be able to explain academic career trajectories in Germany and Switzerland.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark for your comments!

Comment: Many thanks @user2705196 for your comments!